# Django ORM query optimization

Tags: django, postgresql, optimization, orm, django-queryset

I am trying to optimize a database query for the following models:

Conversation model:

```
class Conversation(_BaseModel):
    is_test = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    meta = JSONField(default=dict)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    bot_version = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    listen_mode = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Message model:

```
class Message(_BaseModel):

    conversation = models.ForeignKey(
        'Conversation', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages'
    )
timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    message = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    response = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    data = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    meta = JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
```

The query is:

```
conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(
                ~Q(messages__message='[{"text": "", "type": "text"}]') | ~Q(messages__message='[{"type": "text", "text": ""}]')
            )
```

But I am getting a lag as its so slow since the Message table in the DB has over 5 million rows.
So I read up and tried to use DB indexes where I added an index to the message field in the Message table.

```
message = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

and I was hit with an error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: index row size 3096 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "bot_api_message_message_00003"
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing
```

This is when I stumbled upon a solution that ended up with me creating a migration file with the altered message field and manually write sql  to create an index in the DB using the MD5 of the message field like

```
operations = [

    migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(

        state_operations = [
            migrations.AlterField(
                model_name='message',
                name='message',
                field=models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True, null=True),
            ),
        ],

        database_operations=[
            migrations.RunSQL(sql="""
                CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY "bot_api_message_message_00004"
                ON "bot_api_message"(md5("message")) 
                WHERE md5("message") != md5('[{"type": "text", "text": ""}]')
                OR md5("message") != md5('[{"text": "", "type": "text"}]');
            """,
            reverse_sql="""
                DROP INDEX "bot_api_message_message_00004";
            """),
        ],
    ),
```

But after this, the DB query is still very very slow, what am I doing wrong here?? PLease help.

Comment: Is it possible to change how your data is stored? Could you pull out that `type` text into a field on `Message` so you could compare it directly there? The problem is that you're attempting to query a text field can't be indexed in Postgres which results in a full table seek. If you can scale that down to a smaller field it will likely do better.

Comment: In regards to your index, you I'd imagine you'd have to generate a query that checks the md5 hash of the message field.